# How to display dynamic view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a title as processed with three textview and an images
and then another title with same three textview.
How to create this in dynamic layout? Since I need this to generate in dynamic in android.
I am new to this. please give me an idea.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: which layout is the container?

Comment: Show us your code! This isn't a "do your homework for you" website.

Comment: i don't want to create this in listview because i need to provide this in layout because similar to this three items are displaying with different titles

Comment: this is a sample screenshot extracted from a page which i need to create dynamically in layout @ItzikSamara

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout mContainer;
public void onCreate(Bundle) {
   setContentView(R.layout.container);
   mContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewByid(R.id.coainter);
   View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.id.inflaterView);
   view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   mContainer.addView(view,1);
```

Info -
 create the XML you need to add the Views inside.
 create the view you need to Dyanmiclly add (inflate or create it)
 set the LayoutParams according to the Conatiner.
 add the View to the Conatiner the number 1 is the location inside the Container.
 of crouse this is an Example i just followed your image.
 you can use `mConatiner.addView(view)` this will insert them according to the Container Choice

Hope it Helps.